# GPO does not get applied immediatly - normal behaviour?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, sccm

We are currently testing an environment in which we roll out pc's with SCCM. We've been having trouble for a while now with computers on which we deploy XP do not show up as "in the domain" or with the SCCM client recognized. We still do not know what the problem is, but one of the symptoms (possibly the reason, sort of) is the BITS service not being started.

I tried working around the problem by making a GPO which sets it to automatic, but after my last deploy I noticed one computer was not added once again. I checked the pc, and lo and behold the service was still set to manual and was stopped. No GPO's were applied, though the computer was definately in the domain (and yes, in the right OU).

Does anyone know if GPO's are supposed to be applied after a computer starts up having been added to the domain before? I'd say they are, but right now I'm doubting everything...

Answer (score 5):

> By default, computer Group Policy is updated in the background every 90 minutes, with a random offset of 0 to 30 minutes. In addition to background updates, Group Policy for the computer is always updated when the system starts.

Fetched from technet.microsoft.com

Comment: so basically there's an anomaly there, as the computer has only just been deployed and started for the first time, so it should have gotten applied

Answer (score 0):

Please run GPRESULT and look into the output. This will give you more detailed information on policies etcetera. Maybe the policy did run but you misconfigured it.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/expert/gpresults.mspx

Comment: that's what I used to check if it was applied, and it was not